# CSS Помогите расположить блоки на странице!

Tags: html, css

Страница оформления заказа:
Не получается  `div .x-checkout__order-info-holder` с кратким инфо о заказе поставить справа!!
Разбиваю на 2 вертикальные части.

Левая часть - Поля оформления(И.Ф.О., Вид оплаты и тд.) Правая часть - `div` с краткой инфо о заказе ( назв товара, сколько, картинка товара, сколько к оплате).
Посмотрите, может я в `HTML` что то не так записал, в `CSS` хотел попробовать через `display: table-cell`, но что то не работает ((
Вот HTML:

```css
.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-checkout__form-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-form__content {
  width: 500px;
}

.x-order-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.x-checkout__form-holder,
.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-form__content {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.x-checkout__form-holder,
.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  width: 475px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.x-order-form__content {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.x-order-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.x-checkout__form-holder,
.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-checkout {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-delivery__value-column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 140px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}

.x-order-delivery__text-column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-delivery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-prepare__delivery {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
}

.x-order-total__line_type_total .x-order-total__value {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-order-total__label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.x-order-total__line_type_total .x-order-total__label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.x-order-total__line {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.x-order-prepare__total {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
}

.x-order-product__data {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  color: #989898;
}

.x-order-product__title {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-order-product__title-holder {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 2.6em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.x-order-product__info-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-product__image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.x-order-product__image-holder {
  position: relative;
  height: 58px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.x-order-product__image-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-product {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-prepare__list {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.x-order-prepare__header {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.x-order-prepare__content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.x-order-prepare {
  padding: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4854a2, #772088);
}

.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  width: 475px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#customer_details div .x-input__field {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#customer_details div input[type=text] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

#customer_details div input[type=email] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

#customer_details div div div div div .x-order-form-row__label {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="of-zakaza">
  <div class="x-checkout">
    <div class="x-checkout__form-holder" data-qaid="client_info">
      <form class="x-order-form" method="post">
        <div class="x-order-form__content">
          <div class="x-order-form-row">
            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
            <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative">
              <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe">Выберите способ оплаты</span></span>
                <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

                <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
                  <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                                                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                                                    <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            $(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
              $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
            });
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
              var $target = $(e.target);
              if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
                $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
              }
            });
            $('.x-drop-down__list-item').click(function() {
              $('#payment_option').val($(this).children().text());
              $('#tupe').html($(this).children().html());
            });
          </script>

          <div class="x-shipping-form-row">
            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ доставки:</div>
            <div class="x-shipping-form-row__field x-shipping-form-row__field_pos_relative">
              <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="shipping_option">
                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe-shipping">Выберите способ доставки</span></span>
                <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="shipping_option" name="shipping_option" value="">

                <ul class="x-drop-down__list-shipping  js-dropdown-shipping">
                  <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Новая Почта</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text">
                            <img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Деливери</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            $(".x-shipping-form-row__field").click(function() {
              $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
            });
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
              var $target = $(e.target);
              if ($target.closest(".x-shipping-form-row__field").length == 0) {
                $(".x-drop-down__list-shipping").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_shipping-active");
              }
            });
            $('.x-drop-down__list-item-shipping').click(function() {
              $('#shipping_option').val($(this).children().text());
              $('#tupe-shipping').html($(this).children().html());
            });
          </script>
          <div>
            <div data-reactroot="">
              <div>
                <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                  <input class="b-input__field" name="oblast" placeholder="Введите область (Киевская обл.)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                  <noscript></noscript>
                </div>
                <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                  <input class="b-input__field" name="city" placeholder="Введите город (Киев)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                  <noscript></noscript>
                </div>
                <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                  <input class="b-input__field" name="warehouse" placeholder="Введите номер отделения (#199)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                  <noscript></noscript>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div data-reactroot="">
                  <div>
                    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">ФИО получателя:</div>
                    <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                      <input class="b-input__field" name="firstName" placeholder="Имя" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                      <noscript></noscript>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                      <input class="b-input__field" name="lastName" placeholder="Фамилия" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                      <noscript></noscript>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                      <input class="b-input__field" name="secondName" placeholder="Отчество" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                      <noscript></noscript>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-form-row">
                    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Email:</div>
                    <div class="x-input " data-qaid="client_email"><input type="email" class="x-input__field qa-test-email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                      <!-- react-empty: 53 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- react-empty: 54 -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-form-row">
                    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Телефон:</div>
                    <div class="x-input" data-qaid="client_phone"><input type="text" class="x-input__field qa-test-phone" placeholder="(093)-123-4567" value="" maxlength="20" data-qaid="input_field">
                      <!-- react-empty: 59 -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-form-row">
                    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Комментарий:</div>
                    <div class="x-input"><textarea class="x-input__field" data-qaid="notes_input" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Укажите по желанию доп.инфо по заказу, пожелания, цвет и тд. товара!" rows="3"></textarea>
                      <!-- react-empty: 72 -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
                    <div class="x-order-total">
                      <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                        <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                        <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-form__accept">
                    <div class="x-order-accept"><span class="x-button x-button_width_full x-button_theme_purple" data-qaid="create_order_btn"><span class="x-button__text qa-test-create-order">Оформить заказ</span></span>
                      <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                      <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-form__agreement">
                    <div class="x-order-agreement">
                      <!-- react-text: 90 -->Подтверждая заказ вы соглашаетесь с
                      <!-- /react-text --><a class="x-order-agreement__link" href="https://prom.ua/privacy-policy" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
                      <div class="x-hint x-hint_position_bottom-left x-hidden">
                        <div class="x-hint__wrapper">
                          <div class="x-hint__body"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
      </form>
      </div>


      <div class="x-checkout__order-info-holder" data-qaid="order_info">
        <div class="x-order-prepare">
          <div class="x-order-prepare__content">
            <div class="x-order-prepare__header">
              <div>Ваш заказ</div>
            </div>
            <div class="x-order-prepare__list">
              <div class="x-order-product" data-qaid="product">
                <div class="x-order-product__image-cell">
                  <div class="x-order-product__image-holder">
                    <img class="x-order-product__image" src="https://images.ua.prom.st/1166108104_w100_h100_energy_gv_black.jpg" title="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия" alt="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-product__info-cell">
                  <div class="x-order-product__title-holder">
                    <a class="x-order-product__title" data-qaid="product_name" href="https://odessa.prom.ua/p695677474-azimut-energy-besplatnaya.html" target="_blank">Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x-order-product__data">
                    <div>
                      <!-- react-text: 110 -->Цена:
                      <!-- /react-text -->
                      <span class="x-order-product__price" data-qaid="product_price">2&nbsp;886 грн.
                                                </span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-qaid="quantity_field">
                      <!-- react-text: 113 -->Количество:
                      <!-- /react-text -->
                      <!-- react-text: 114 -->1
                      <!-- /react-text -->
                      <!-- react-text: 115 -->шт.
                      <!-- /react-text -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="x-order-product__presence">
                      <!-- react-text: 117 -->Наличие:
                      <!-- /react-text --><span>В наличии</span></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
              <div class="x-order-total">
                <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_save x-hidden"><span class="x-order-total__value"></span></div>
                <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                  <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                  <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="x-order-prepare__delivery">
              <div class="x-order-delivery">
                <div class="x-order-delivery__text-column">
                  <!-- react-text: 131 -->Стоимость доставки
                  <!-- /react-text -->
                  <div class="x-order-delivery__text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-delivery__value-column"><span data-qaid="delivery_price"><!-- react-text: 135 -->Уточняйте у продавца<!-- /react-text --></span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Поможет кто с этой задачкой ? float не получается ... display: table-cell так же не выходит ( Поля с формой слева, блок с инфо заказом справа!! Помогите )

Comment: Привет, завтра на работе сделаю, если никто сегодня не сделает. ))

Comment: Ок, рад тебя тут увидеть )) Спокойной ночи тогда и до завтра!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого?

```css
.of-zakaza {
  display: flex;
}




.x-checkout__form-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-form__content {
  width: 500px;
}

.x-order-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}


.x-order-form__content {
  max-width: 500px;
}



.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  width: 475px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.x-order-form__content {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.x-order-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}



.x-checkout {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-delivery__value-column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 140px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}

.x-order-delivery__text-column {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-delivery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-prepare__delivery {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
}

.x-order-total__line_type_total .x-order-total__value {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-order-total__label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.x-order-total__line_type_total .x-order-total__label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.x-order-total__line {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.x-order-prepare__total {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
}

.x-order-product__data {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  color: #989898;
}

.x-order-product__title {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-order-product__title-holder {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 2.6em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.x-order-product__info-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-product__image {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.x-order-product__image-holder {
  position: relative;
  height: 58px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1f0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.x-order-product__image-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-order-product {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.x-order-prepare__list {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.x-order-prepare__header {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.x-order-prepare__content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.x-order-prepare {
  padding: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4854a2, #772088);
}

.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  width: 475px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#customer_details div .x-input__field {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#customer_details div input[type=text] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

#customer_details div input[type=email] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

#customer_details div div div div div .x-order-form-row__label {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="of-zakaza">
    <div class="x-checkout">
        <div class="x-checkout__form-holder" data-qaid="client_info">
            <form class="x-order-form" method="post">
                <div class="x-order-form__content">
                    <div class="x-order-form-row">
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative">
                            <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
                                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe">Выберите способ оплаты</span></span>
                                <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
                                <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

                                <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x-shipping-form-row">
                        <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ доставки:</div>
                        <div class="x-shipping-form-row__field x-shipping-form-row__field_pos_relative">
                            <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="shipping_option">
                                <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span id="tupe-shipping">Выберите способ доставки</span></span>
                                <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
                                <input type="hidden" id="shipping_option" name="shipping_option" value="">

                                <ul class="x-drop-down__list-shipping  js-dropdown-shipping">
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Новая Почта</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item-shipping js-item">
                                        <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Деливери</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div data-reactroot="">
                        <div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="oblast" placeholder="Введите область (Киевская обл.)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="city" placeholder="Введите город (Киев)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="warehouse" placeholder="Введите номер отделения (#199)" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-reactroot="">
                        <div>
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">ФИО получателя:</div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="first-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="firstName" placeholder="Имя" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="last-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="lastName" placeholder="Фамилия" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                            <div class="b-order-prepare__field b-input" data-qaid="second-name-input-np">
                                <input class="b-input__field" name="secondName" placeholder="Отчество" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <noscript></noscript>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Email:</div>
                            <div class="x-input " data-qaid="client_email"><input type="email" class="x-input__field qa-test-email" maxlength="255" placeholder="Email" value="" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <!-- react-empty: 53 -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- react-empty: 54 -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Телефон:</div>
                            <div class="x-input" data-qaid="client_phone"><input type="text" class="x-input__field qa-test-phone" placeholder="(093)-123-4567" value="" maxlength="20" data-qaid="input_field">
                                <!-- react-empty: 59 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form-row">
                            <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Комментарий:</div>
                            <div class="x-input"><textarea class="x-input__field" data-qaid="notes_input" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Укажите по желанию доп.инфо по заказу, пожелания, цвет и тд. товара!" rows="3"></textarea>
                                <!-- react-empty: 72 -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
                            <div class="x-order-total">
                                <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                                    <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                                    <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form__accept">
                            <div class="x-order-accept"><span class="x-button x-button_width_full x-button_theme_purple" data-qaid="create_order_btn"><span class="x-button__text qa-test-create-order">Оформить заказ</span></span>
                                <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                                <div class="x-order-accept__min-order x-hidden"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-form__agreement">
                            <div class="x-order-agreement">
                                <!-- react-text: 90 -->Подтверждая заказ вы соглашаетесь с
                                <!-- /react-text --><a class="x-order-agreement__link" href="https://prom.ua/privacy-policy" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
                                <div class="x-hint x-hint_position_bottom-left x-hidden">
                                    <div class="x-hint__wrapper">
                                        <div class="x-hint__body"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-checkout__order-info-holder" data-qaid="order_info">
        <div class="x-order-prepare">
            <div class="x-order-prepare__content">
                <div class="x-order-prepare__header">
                    <div>Ваш заказ</div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__list">
                    <div class="x-order-product" data-qaid="product">
                        <div class="x-order-product__image-cell">
                            <div class="x-order-product__image-holder">
                                <img class="x-order-product__image" src="https://images.ua.prom.st/1166108104_w100_h100_energy_gv_black.jpg" title="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия" alt="Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-product__info-cell">
                            <div class="x-order-product__title-holder">
                                <a class="x-order-product__title" data-qaid="product_name" href="https://odessa.prom.ua/p695677474-azimut-energy-besplatnaya.html" target="_blank">Azimut Energy 29 GV | Бесплатная доставка | Кешбек за отзыв | Подарок | Гарантия</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x-order-product__data">
                                <div>
                                    <!-- react-text: 110 -->Цена:
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <span class="x-order-product__price" data-qaid="product_price">2&nbsp;886 грн.
                                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <div data-qaid="quantity_field">
                                    <!-- react-text: 113 -->Количество:
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <!-- react-text: 114 -->1
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <!-- react-text: 115 -->шт.
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="x-order-product__presence">
                                    <!-- react-text: 117 -->Наличие:
                                    <!-- /react-text --><span>В наличии</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__total">
                    <div class="x-order-total">
                        <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_save x-hidden"><span class="x-order-total__value"></span></div>
                        <div class="x-order-total__line x-order-total__line_type_total">
                            <div class="x-order-total__label">Всего</div>
                            <div class="x-order-total__value"><span data-qaid="total_price">2 886 грн.</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x-order-prepare__delivery">
                    <div class="x-order-delivery">
                        <div class="x-order-delivery__text-column">
                            <!-- react-text: 131 -->Стоимость доставки
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                            <div class="x-order-delivery__text"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-order-delivery__value-column"><span data-qaid="delivery_price"><!-- react-text: 135 -->Уточняйте у продавца<!-- /react-text --></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <script src="./checkout.js"></script> Свои скрипты подключай подобным образом. например после всей html разметки.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас 2 проблемы в HTML-разметке:

1) Избыточность классов и вообще div-элементов - столько реально не нужно.
2) Заметил несколько тэгов , задуманных как обёртка, но после них идут ещё несколько обёрток с div-ами, у которых уже есть классы. Вот при такой вложенности тэгов эти неназванные div-ы ещё больше запутывают.

Я минут 30 пробовал найти проблему, но у Вас слишком много тэгов с какими-то суперназваниями. Это мешает, а не помогает разбираться в коде и структурировать его. 
Должно выйти так, как я указал ниже:

```css
.x-checkout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.x-checkout__form-holder,.x-checkout__order-info-holder {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="of-zakaza">
  <div class="x-checkout">
    <div class="x-checkout__form-holder"></div>
    <div class="x-checkout__order-info-holder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А оно не срабатывает. По идее, .x-checkout__order-info-holder должен быть дочерним элементом .x-checkout, а получается по факту так, что это дочерний элемент.x-checkout__form-holder, из-за чего display:flex; не срабатывает на обоих элементах.

Это видно из консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как по мне, так проще переделать. Вы, наверное, конструктор сайтов использовали. У них характерная избыточность тегов.

Comment: Супер названия это подражение БЭМ и прочим псевдо-инструментам, тссс, не спугните ТСа...

Comment: Да, тут я намудрил )) Сейчас буду переделывать!!